# A calculus question related to the nonnegative definite functions

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I am looking for some sufficient conditions for an even, continuous, nonnegative, non increasing function $f(x)$ on $R$ such that

$$
\int_0^\infty \cos(xz) f(z) d z \ge 0 \qquad\text{for all $x\ge 0$.}
\tag{1}
$$

I have a such function $f$. It has a complicated form involving some special functions. But it is an even, continuous, nonnegative and non increasing function. The goal is to see if (1) is satisfied. A direct calculation is hard.

Examples for these functions include: $(1+x^2)^{-1}$, $(1+|x|)^{-1}$, $\exp(-|x|)$, etc. One counterexample is $(1+x^4)^{-1}$.

This question is related the characterization of the nonnegative definite functions on $R$.

Thanks for any hints or references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [On positivity of Fourier transforms](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ74_01%2FS0004972700047511a.pdf&code=3b5549fe1a8edfaf28e851f47f408cbf); one sufficient condition is that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

there are other sufficient conditions, see for example [On the positivity of Fourier transforms](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3155)

a necessary and sufficient condition is not known.

Comment: Thanks Carlo Beenakker for the reference. As is mentioned in p.2 lines 9--14 of this paper, it is not clear for the bell-shaped functions. Unfortunately my function $f$ falls into this case. Another non-convex function which has positive Fourier-cosine transform is $(1+x^2)^{-1}$.

Comment: Is there an analogous result in higher dimensional euclidean space?