# Conditions for positivity of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Assume you are given a non-negative, continuous, radial function $f\in L^q(\mathbb{R}^3)$ (for any $q\geq 1$).

Are there any conditions which would guarantee that the Fourier transform of $f$, that is $\hat{f}(p)$, is also non-negative?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the three-dimensional Fourier transform $F(\vec{p})$, of the radial function $f(r)$ has Fourier transform

$$F(\vec{p})=\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^\pi d\theta \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\;e^{ ipr\cos\theta}f(r) r^2\sin\theta$$
$$\qquad=\frac{4\pi}{p}\int_0^\infty rf(r)\sin(pr)\,dr,\;\;{\rm with}\;\;p=|\vec{p}|.$$

so you're asking when the Fourier-sine-transform $S(p)$ of $rf(r)$ will be (pointwise) positive for $p>0$. A sufficient condition is that $rf(r)$ is a decreasing function of $r>0$, see [On positivity of Fourier transforms.](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FBAZ%2FBAZ74_01%2FS0004972700047511a.pdf&code=c132cf865945b7fc535dff80e4f96db5)

For a related question, see [this MO post.](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193849/a-calculus-question-related-to-the-nonnegative-definite-functions/193866#193866)

For the connection to [Bochner's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_theorem) theorem: the OP's question amounts to finding a function that is both positive and positive-definite, since positive functions have positive-definite Fourier transforms.

Comment: I am somewhat puzzled. My understanding is that the OP has a radial function (which happens to be positive). By Bochner, he needs to check whether this is positive definite, and this is exactly what is done in the reference in my answer. Presumably, checking that a function is positive is not hard (well, it can be, of course...) FINDING a function which is positive and positive definite is not rocket science since the Gaussian density works.

Comment: @IgorRivin --- indeed, theorem 2.4.1 cited in your answer, applied to $\mathbb{R}^3$, gives the same condition as above: $\int_0^\infty rf(r)sin(pr)dr>0$ for $p>0$. The OP's question, as I understand it, is: what are the requirements on $f(r)>0$ such that this integral condition holds; I only  have one sufficient requirement ($rf(r)$ decreasing) --- can this be improved?

Comment: Well, it is not entirely clear what the OP's question is. I agree that a characterization of radial functions such that both the function and its fourier transform are positive and positive definite sounds tractable (with enough regularity thrown in...)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker $f(r)>0$, $rf(r)$ is $0$ at $0$, it will never be decreasing for all $r$

Comment: @TanyaVladi --- try $f(r)=1/r^2$

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, true, I  assumed function $f(0)<\infty$. Sufficient condition with  very limited applicability. Do you know of any other?

Answer (score 4):

The magic words are "Bochner's theorem" (which says that the Fourier transform is positive for positive definite functions). For more on radial functions see Theorem 2.4.1 in [this book.](http://www.math.iit.edu/~fass/603_ch2.pdf) (Greg Fasshauer)

Comment: Yeah, but the fact that a function is positive definite does not imply it is pointwise positive, doesn't it?

Comment: @scouser what does that have to do with anything? Your function is positive by assumption, and pos. def. since the fourier transform is positive.

Comment: maybe I expressed myself incorrect in the comment. My point is that if I treat $f$ as the density of my measure, then the theorem states that $\hat{f}(p)$ is positive definite, but this does not imply that $\hat{f}(p)\geq 0$ pointwise. This is what I meant by non-negative in the question.

Comment: @scouser think inverse fourier transform. FT is positive -> YOUR FUNCTION is p.d.